# How to get second largest value as second value in esper

Tags: sql, complex-event-processing, esper

I'm trying to get the second value as the second largest value in Esper. But, unfortunately, it says the nested subquery is not working. So, how can I get the second largest value in Esper?

My Query is as follows:

```
SELECT max(averageTemperature) as Temp1, 
  (
    select max(jfk_alias.averageTemperature) 
    from jfk as jfk_alias 
    where jfk_alias.averageTemperature not in (
      select max(averageTemperature) 
      from jfk) 
) as Temp2
FROM JFK
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use windows functions to order the `averageTemperature` by descending order, then select the 2nd row.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT  averageTemperature,
            dense_rank() over(order by averageTemperature desc) as rn_max
    FROM jfk
) a
WHERE rn_max = 2
```

EDIT : `dense_rank` instead of `row_number` per Andrew's suggestion

Comment: It's not working return errors

Comment: If there are multiple occurrences of the second largest value, row_number will arbitrarily "rank" them. You are probably better off using dense_rank. Dense_rank will return 2 for all the rows with the second highest value.

Comment: @MohammadMainulHasan - try aliasing the derived table

Comment: Maybe the `row_number()` function is different in sql esper ?

Answer (score 0):

The "sorted" aggregation function is what you want to use. It has various access methods.